# Output lines in CSV where a particular column is not empty and another is

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have some CSV, the first seven columns of which looks like this:

```
ID,SerialNo,SortKey,BookTitle,BookSubtitle,AuthorName,EditorName
```

I need to output all lines where the AuthorName is empty, and the EditorName is not. The desired end result is output.csv which contains just the second line of the three below.

```
123,789,1,War and Peace,A novel,Tolstoy,
456,987,2,Oxford English Dictionary,A book of words,,Oxford editors
789,123,3,Romeo and Juliet,A play,Shakespeare,
```

I'm using Gitbash for Windows. Is there an awk solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `,` as our field separator, you are asking for lines where field 6 does not exist (`!$6`) and field 7 does (`$7`) giving:

```
awk -F, '!$6 && $7' input.csv
```

Comment: You could reduce to just `'!$6 && $7'` :)

Comment: With the addition of the source file to the command, this works well.